# Can you turn a key stuck on the inside of a door from the outside using an electromagnet?

Tags: electromagnetism

i got woken up by a horrible sensation of being blasted by pulses of radiation and ringing ears this morning, followed by short period of silence and then the sound of the cellar door next room unlocking. i started screaming at the top of my lungs when whoever was breaking in started slowly opening the door to my room after he spent a about a minute exploring my cellar in complete darkness, and that made him quietly close the door and leave.

after recovering from the shock 10 minutes later i finally got up and checked out the cellar, and the door was locked. there is no other way to get in or out of the cellar other than that door and the one to my room.

apart from being delusional the only other explanation i can think of is that the horrible pulsing sensation was a strong magnetic field being turned along with my key on the inside of the door. He must have tried it on my front door close to where I was sleeping when I first felt it, where he had no success other than waking me up since there was no key on the inside of it. I couldn't hear or feel it before I heard the cellar door unlock and lock again when he left.

Some pictures of both sides of the door and the key: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWQSB.jpg

i checked to see if the key is magnetic already, and it certainly is. i really need confirmation on whether or not this is possible and if you can actually feel a strong magnetic field since i cant find any information on this on the internet, all search queries i tried just lead to stuff about electromagnetic locks and how to break into them.

EDIT:

I figured out what what the pulsing was. Not radiation, not sleep paralysis, but simply being connected to the 220V power outlet through my heating blanket. I've been using it for a few weeks since I just moved and the central heating isn't working yet, so it's the only source of heat I had. Turns out it must have overheated and burned the insulation so thin that my body was connected, albeit through a large enough resistance that i didn't feel any pain. The pulsing must have been blanket controlling heat output by ramping the voltage up and down. Feel pretty stupid for not thinking of this earlier, but the sensation was so alien and completely unlike how you'd expect electric shock to feel like. If it hadn't stopped after 30 seconds i might have figured it out eventually, but the way it dropped off felt exactly like someone holding a transmitter walking away. The walkie-talkie beep didn't come from outside, but rather the blanket controller's overheating or overcurrent protection. It had never made any noise before and it didn't even look like it had speaker.

I'm dismissing the whole break in as hallucination in state of panic and electric shock, and I'd like to thank everyone here who helped trying to actually answer the question.

Comment: A dream would be a better explanation.

Comment: could you explain why the turning of the key is not possible?

Comment: Well.. If you key is magnetic.. And you have $100M in your basement to attract a thug engineer, then it's possible. But still a very serious engineering challenge. If that thug would be me, i would need a startor of avery big motor ($5k), a serious servo drive with custom software (another $5k), probably a month of preparations. Then it could work, maybe. But then the risk, the moral aspects... I wouldn't do it. So unless there is someone trained with this drill (which i doubt), it is probably a dream.

Comment: That's an old lever lock. They're not used any more because they're very easy to pick. A few weeks hobby training vs an engineering project that would probably get you a degree...

Comment: If the key is magnetic, and you have a big enough magnet, then yes. A strong enough magnetic field can induce enough force in a magnetic object to turn it. Either the object will move, or it will deform under the pressure. As to how practical this is, it's not. Basic lock picking will work on most residential locks, and a basic vibrating pick gun makes easy work of home locks. And bump keys, crow bar, a well placed kick, Etc.

Comment: Much easier to pick the lock rather than having fancy tools, check the video on YouTube. So far there hasn't been conclusive experiments that Human can feel magnetic fields so it's sounds more like a panic attack

Comment: I think it would only be possible if the rest of the lock was from a non-magnetic material. The magnetic field required to turn the key would also cause all internal metal parts to be magnetic and they, with the key itself, would "stick" together with tremendous forces.

Comment: So this guy using a monster magnet unlocked your cellar door, you made some noises and he left shortly afterwards and, miraculously the guy re-locked the cellar door with the monster magnet. Does this seem likely?

Comment: leave off the magic mushrooms.

Comment: you have been watching too much TV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it would be possible to do that. Since you would align the magnet by the key axis a strong magnet would pull the key towards you but it would not really turn the key if you rotate the magnet since you only have a solid piece of metal, you need two different magnetic contacts in the plane of rotation to guarantee the desired movement.
Also since there are metal parts inside the lock everything would be pulled.
As for the feeling a magnetic field part, if you have ever done an MRI exam and you didn't fell anything it proves that. A typical MRI machine had up to 3 times the magnetic field strength of a junkyard magnet, and it doesn't affect your ears pressure whatsoever.